# Converting a table into XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml, html-table

So basically, I've been trying to convert an HTML table into XML (with PHP).

I don't have any functioning code. It should go from:

```
<table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th align="left">label1</th>
                          <th align="left">label2</th>
                          <th align="left">label3</th>
                          <th align="left">label4</th>       
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>         
                        <tr>
                            <td>DATA1</td>
                            <td>DATA2</td>
                            <td>DATA3</td>
                            <td>DATA4</td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
</table>
```

To something like the following:

```
<root>
    <0>
        <label1>DATA1</label1>
        <label2>DATA2</label2>
        <label3>DATA3</label3>
        <label4>DATA4</label4>
    </0>
</root>
```

I wasn't able to locate any functions, or code to do this.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking is usually solved with the XSLTProcessor functionality available in PHP. The particular transformation is done using an XSL file.

Here's the special case that you request

Note that I use <R0> ... <R1>, not <0> <1> as it would not be a valid tag name for an XML element.

xml-trans.php  (the CLI file to execute)

```
<?php

$xslDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xslDoc->load('thexhtml.xsl');

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load('thexhtml.html');

$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$proc->importStylesheet($xslDoc);
echo $proc->transformToXML($xmlDoc);

?>
```

thexhtml.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:for-each select="table/tbody/tr">
        <xsl:variable name="rowNum" select="position()-1" />
        <xsl:element name="R{$rowNum}" >
          <xsl:for-each select="td">
            <xsl:variable name="colNum" select="position()" />
            <xsl:variable name="header" select="/table/thead/tr/th[position()=$colNum]"/>
            <xsl:element name="{$header}" >
              <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

thexhtml.html  (With some more lines in the table for testing.)

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th align="left">label1</th>
      <th align="left">label2</th>
      <th align="left">label3</th>
      <th align="left">label4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>DATA11</td>
      <td>DATA12</td>
      <td>DATA13</td>
      <td>DATA14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DATA21</td>
      <td>DATA22</td>
      <td>DATA23</td>
      <td>DATA24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DATA31</td>
      <td>DATA32</td>
      <td>DATA33</td>
      <td>DATA34</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My testing result

```
php xsl-trans.php > theresult.xml
```

theresult.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <R0>
    <label1>DATA11</label1>
    <label2>DATA12</label2>
    <label3>DATA13</label3>
    <label4>DATA14</label4>
  </R0>
  <R1>
    <label1>DATA21</label1>
    <label2>DATA22</label2>
    <label3>DATA23</label3>
    <label4>DATA24</label4>
  </R1>
  <R2>
    <label1>DATA31</label1>
    <label2>DATA32</label2>
    <label3>DATA33</label3>
    <label4>DATA34</label4>
  </R2>
</root>
```

I hope it helps